# Capturar Header do SOAP com PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, header

Boa Tarde

Estou a consumir um WSDL de um Webservice onde após o login e após cada requisição conforme XML retornado abaixo me é apresentada as seguintes tags no head do Soap

```html
<Sequencia> 1 </ Sequencia>
<SessionId> 4b4uc2536530-941f-44e6-ab95-8ee7179fb016 </ SessionId>
```

Como regra de segurança devo salvar estes e na próxima requisão usar os dados para a próxima requisição gravar, nesta nova requisição sera gerada nova sessão e sequencia e eu devo guarda-las para outra requisição e assim por diante.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <Sessao xmlns="http://dominio.com.br">
            <Sequencia>1</Sequencia>
            <SessionId>4b4uc2536530-941f-44e6-ab95-8ee7179fb016</SessionId>
            <Versao>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <SituacaoCache>Inalterado</SituacaoCache>
                <VersaoAtual>0</VersaoAtual>
                <ReleaseAtual>0</ReleaseAtual>
                <ProximaAtualizacao>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ProximaAtualizacao>
                <Minutos>0</Minutos>
                <VersaoDisponivel>
                    <VersaoRota>0</VersaoRota>
                    <VersaoBanco>0</VersaoBanco>
                    <ReleaseBanco>0</ReleaseBanco>
                    <Compilacao>0</Compilacao>
                </VersaoDisponivel>
                <QuantidadeReleases>0</QuantidadeReleases>
            </Versao>
        </Sessao>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <LogOnResponse xmlns="http://dominio.com.br">
            <LogOnResult>
                <Excecoes />
                <DatabaseCount>0</DatabaseCount>
                <Retorno>
                    <Id>18659</Id>
                    <Nome>NOME</Nome>
                    <Email>nome@provedor.com</Email>
                    <Endereco />
                    <Bairro />
                    <Cidade />
                    <Estado />
                    <Pais />
                    <Cep />
                    <LogOn>login</LogOn>
                    <DataNascimento>1984-09-17T00:00:00</DataNascimento>
                    <RG />
                    <Cpf>000.000.000-00</Cpf>
                    <Telefone />
                    <Celular />
                    <Configuracoes />
                    <Ativo>true</Ativo>
                    <Tema>Azul</Tema>
                    <Perfil>
                        <Id>12</Id>
                        <Nome>Sites Externos</Nome>
                        <Descricao />
                        <NiveisAcesso>
                            <CLPerfilNivelAcesso>
                                <Id>11</Id>
                                <Perfil>
                                    <Id>12</Id>
                                    <Nome>Sites Externos</Nome>
                                    <Descricao />
                                    <NiveisAcesso />
                                    <Modulos />
                                    <Atividades />
                                </Perfil>
                                <NivelAcesso>
                                    <Id>1</Id>
                                    <Nome>Usuário</Nome>
                                    <Codigo>1</Codigo>
                                    <Descricao />
                                </NivelAcesso>
                            </CLPerfilNivelAcesso>
                        </NiveisAcesso>
                        <Modulos>
                            <CLPerfilModulo>
                                <Id>19</Id>
                                <Perfil>
                                    <Id>12</Id>
                                    <Nome>Sites Externos</Nome>
                                    <Descricao />
                                    <NiveisAcesso />
                                    <Modulos />
                                    <Atividades />
                                </Perfil>
                                <Modulo>
                                    <Id>9</Id>
                                    <Nome>Portais</Nome>
                                    <Codigo>256</Codigo>
                                    <Descricao />
                                </Modulo>
                            </CLPerfilModulo>
                            <CLPerfilModulo>
                                <Id>20</Id>
                                <Perfil>
                                    <Id>12</Id>
                                    <Nome>Sites Externos</Nome>
                                    <Descricao />
                                    <NiveisAcesso />
                                    <Modulos />
                                    <Atividades />
                                </Perfil>
                                <Modulo>
                                    <Id>2</Id>
                                    <Nome>Processos</Nome>
                                    <Codigo>2</Codigo>
                                    <Descricao />
                                </Modulo>
                            </CLPerfilModulo>
                        </Modulos>
                        <Atividades />
                    </Perfil>
                    <Skype />
                    <EmpresaAtual>
                        <Id>0</Id>
                        <SituacaoCache>Inalterado</SituacaoCache>
                        <Nome />
                        <RazaoSocial />
                        <Cnpj />
                        <Endereco />
                        <Bairro />
                        <Cidade />
                        <Estado />
                        <Pais />
                        <Cep />
                        <SistemaWooba>
                            <Id>0</Id>
                            <SituacaoCache>Inalterado</SituacaoCache>
                            <Codigo />
                            <Nome />
                            <Wooba>0</Wooba>
                            <Observacoes />
                            <TemBilhetes>true</TemBilhetes>
                            <PermiteBilheteSemLocalizador>false</PermiteBilheteSemLocalizador>
                            <Campos />
                        </SistemaWooba>
                        <SistemaSisav>
                            <Id>0</Id>
                            <SituacaoCache>Inalterado</SituacaoCache>
                            <Codigo />
                            <Nome />
                            <Wooba>0</Wooba>
                            <Observacoes />
                            <TemBilhetes>true</TemBilhetes>
                            <PermiteBilheteSemLocalizador>false</PermiteBilheteSemLocalizador>
                            <Campos />
                        </SistemaSisav>
                        <Arquivo>
                            <Nome />
                            <Extensao />
                            <Hash />
                            <Conteudo />
                        </Arquivo>
                    </EmpresaAtual>
                    <DeveAlterarSenha>false</DeveAlterarSenha>
                    <SenhaNuncaExpira>false</SenhaNuncaExpira>
                    <DataAlteracaoSenha>2015-11-10T14:53:45.647</DataAlteracaoSenha>
                    <DataAlteracaoEmail>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DataAlteracaoEmail>
                    <DataAlteracaoCelular>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DataAlteracaoCelular>
                    <Perguntas>0</Perguntas>
                    <UsaBloqueioIP>false</UsaBloqueioIP>
                    <JornadaTrabalho>
                        <Id>0</Id>
                        <Nome />
                        <Prioridade>0</Prioridade>
                    </JornadaTrabalho>
                    <Sexo>Masculino</Sexo>
                    <TokenSSO />
                    <Arquivo>
                        <Nome />
                        <Extensao />
                        <Hash />
                        <Conteudo />
                    </Arquivo>
                </Retorno>
            </LogOnResult>
        </LogOnResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
<pre>
```

em testes o código PHP abaixo ao ser executado me apresenta a seguinte mensagem
XML não existe

```html
$UrlWSLogin = new SoapClient('https://ws.dominio.com.br/integrador/integrador.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));
//print_r($UrlWS->__getFunctions());

$MetodoLoginWS = 'LogOn';

$DadosLoginWs = array(
    "Sequencia" => "0",
    "SessionId" => "0",
    "prUsuario" => "login",
    "prSenha" => "senha",
);

$ResultadoWS = $UrlWSLogin->$MetodoLoginWS($DadosLoginWs);

//$RespostaWS = '<pre>'.print_r($ResultadoWS,true).'</pre>';

if (isset($ResultadoWS)) {
    //echo '<pre>'. print_r($UrlWSLogin->__getLastResponse());'</pre>';
    
    $XMLws = $UrlWSLogin->__getLastResponse(); // usando __getLastResponse tenho acesso ao header do soap

    if (!$xml = simplexml_load_string("$XMLws")) {
        echo 'XML não existe';
    } else {
        echo $xml->Sessao->SessionId;
    }
    
    echo "Falha ao capturar xml do ws";
}
```

Teria algum tratamento para que eu possa converter as tags do objeto em variaveis assim podendo trabalhar mais fácil com eles como guardar os dados das tags em variaveis?

Comment: Você quer somente obter os nós `Sequencia` e `SessionId` ?

Comment: sim isso mesmo é o que preciso

Comment: Ninguém? Já vi que o bicho é mais difícil de domar do que pensei.

Pois o body do Soap eu consigo ler agora o Head é fogo

Comment: eu ia resnponder, mas vi no seu código algo assim: `// usando __getLastResponse tenho acesso ao header do soap`. Então isso parece contraditório e confuso, haja vista que você quer os header mas ao mesmo tempo diz que os obtêm.

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, vamos lá...
A verdade é que você não deveria precisar de nenhum parser, reader XML para analisar os dados XML retornados pela consulta ao web service via SOAP.
O próprio SOAPClient deveria ser capaz de fazer isso sem análise extra da árvore XML.

> Todos os exemplos abaixo é baseado no XML da resposta do autor da
>   questão.

Isso deveria ser mais ou menos assim:

```
$client = new SoapClient('arquivo WSDL');
$response = $client->LogOn($DadosLoginWs);
print $response->Header->Sessao->Sequencia;
// ...
```

Até onde eu sei o código acima deveria servir muito bem. No entanto, caso você ainda queira analisar o XML, eis aqui como você deveria proceder:

### DOMDocument / DOMDocument::DOMXPath()

```
# Registre corretamente o domínio namespace
$namespaceDomain = 'http://dominio.com.br';
# Isso na verdade é somente XML em string
$xmldata = file_get_contents('http://localhost/soap.xml');

$dom = DOMDocument::loadXML($xmldata);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('sessao', $namespaceDomain);
#retorna DOMNode (servirá de contexto)
$sessao = $xpath->query('//soap:Header/sessao:Sessao')->item(0); 
$sessaoSeq = $xpath->query('sessao:Sequencia', $sessao)->item(0)->nodeValue;
$sessaoId  = $xpath->query('sessao:SessionId', $sessao)->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

### SimpleXMLElement / SimpleXMLElement::xpath()

```
$reader = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldata);
$reader->registerXPathNamespace('sessao', $namespaceDomain);
$sessao = $reader->xpath('//soap:Header/sessao:Sessao');
$sessaoSeq = $sessao[0]->Sequencia;
$sessaoId  = $sessao[0]->SessionId;
```

Como tu podes perceber, é necessário registrar o namespace antes de analisar os nós na árvore XML, do contrário, não funcionará! Isso porque, no seu caso, o nó `Sessao` possui um  namespace, então para acessar seus descendentes você precisa informar o namespace prefix.
O prefixo de namespace pode ser qualquer nome.

---

Links úteis:

- [SimpleXMLElmenet](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.simplexmlelement.php)
- [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)
- [SimpleXMLElement::registerXPathNamespace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php)
- [The DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- [The DOMXPath class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- [DOMXPath::registerNamespace](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php)