# Como enviar parâmetros pelo header do soap e junto parâmetros para o body

Tags: php, soap, header

Estou querendo saber como eu envio o header de um soap e junto o parâmetro que vai ao body. Estou colocando o código que eu já fiz e o soap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<Seguranca xmlns="http://satussistemas.org/">
  <Usuario>string</Usuario>
  <Senha>string</Senha>
</Seguranca>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<pegaArquivoAutomacao xmlns="http://satussistemas.org/">
  <nomeArquivo>string</nomeArquivo>
</pegaArquivoAutomacao>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

E aqui está o código:

```
$client = new SoapClient('Meu WSDL',array());

$auth = array('Seguranca'=>array('Usuario'=>'usuario', 
                                         'Senha'=>'senha')); 

$header = new SoapHeader('pegaArquivoAutomacao','Seguranca',$auth,true);

try{
   $resultProduto = $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
   print_r($resultProduto);
}
   catch (SoapFault $exceptionProduto) {
   echo $exceptionProduto;      
}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98094/capturar-header-do-soap-com-php

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas mesmo assim o valor de retorno esta a vir vazio,  mesmo eu sabendo que o webservice esta a funcionar perfeitamente. Sabem o que pode ser?

Comment: Tente fazer desta forma, sempre utilizo desta forma para adicionar o Header no Request http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php#93460

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas as respostas. Acabei de saber que o servidor não esta deixando eu pegar o arquivo binário, agora que deram liberação ao arquivo esta tudo a funcionar normalmente.